# Opensuse full-screen inside Hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, opensuse

I was having problems trying to configure my hyper-v display resolution with an opensuse machine. My "fullscreen" was really small and it's hard to find the solution so I'd like to add the solution here, in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-First edit the grub config with sudo vi /etc/default/grub and edit the line that starts like GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet..... and before the last " add the next parameter : video=hyperv_fb:1366x768 or select your actual resolution.
-Finally run the command sudo update-bootloader --refresh and reboot. That's it, you should now be able to visualise your screen in full-screen. I hope this info is helpful.